# Reading a csv file(not compiling: comparison between a pointer and integer not allowed)

Tags: c++11

So I am reading a csv file which contains data as:
1920-1970,"3,230","793","1,281","670","352","170",

When I compile the code it throws an error: Comparison between a pointer and integer not allowed, in the code lines where I am comparing as follows:

```
    while(in.peek()!="\"")
```

Full code is:

```
struct Demographics{
int ymin, ymax, popend, popgro, birth, death, immig, emmig;

};
int getcommaint(ifstream& in){
    char c;
    in>>c;
    int retval=0;
    int val=0;
    while(in.peek()!="\""){
        retval*=1000;
        in>>val;
        if(in.peek()==',')
            cin>>c;
        retval+=val;
    }
    in>>c>>c;
    return retval;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Demographics& d){
    ifstream in;
    char c;
    in.open("file.csv");
if(!in.is_open()){
    cout<<"No file found"<<endl;
}
else{


        while(!in.eof()){
        in>>d.ymin>>c>>d.ymax>>c;
        if(in.peek()=="\""){
            d.popend=getcommaint(in);
            d.popgro=getcommaint(in);
            d.birth=getcommaint(in);
            d.death=getcommaint(in);
            d.immig=getcommaint(in);
            d.emmig=getcommaint(in);

        }
        else{
            in>>d.popend>>d.popgro>>d.birth>>d.death>>d.immig>>d.emmig;
        }
        cout<<d.popend<<" "<<d.popgro<<" "<<d.birth<<" "<<d.death<<" " 
        <<d.immig<<" "<<d.emmig<<endl;
        }
    }
    in>>c;
    in.close();
     }
```

I just don't understand this error, as I am a complete beginner in c++. Any help would be appreciated in making this code run.

Comment: `while(in.peek()!="\"")` is wrong because you are trying to compare a `char` (the return value of `in.peek()` with `"\""`, a string. Use `while(in.peek() != '"')`

Comment: I am inclined to vote to close the question as a typo.

Comment: You have to change `if(in.peek()=="\"")` for the same reason.

Comment: `"\""` is a string literal containing `"` as the first character. `'"'` is a character literal that represents the double quote character.